# FlChart LineTouchTooltipData dynamic background color

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I want to create a LineChart using `fl_chart` and I need the tooltip background to change color based on touched spot
for example the color should be determined by this method

```
  Color _getColor(List<int> intervals, double value) {
    if (value >= intervals[0] && value < intervals[1]) {
      return AppConstants.greenColor;
    } else if (value >= intervals[1] && value < intervals[2]) {
      return AppConstants.yellowColor;
    }
    return AppConstants.redColor;
  }
```

current code:

```
LineTouchData(

                  touchTooltipData: LineTouchTooltipData(
                    tooltipBgColor: Colors.red,
                    fitInsideHorizontally: true,
                    fitInsideVertically: true,
                    tooltipRoundedRadius: 100,
                    getTooltipItems: (touchedSpots) {
                      return touchedSpots
                          .map(
                            (e) => LineTooltipItem(
                              e.y.toString(),
                              const TextStyle(),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```